# How can i show child electron BrowserWindow as separate taskbar icon?

Tags: electron, taskbar, childwindow

I have test electron project with two windows.
Now windows are grouped in the taskbar (see the ACTUAL part on screenshot).
I want each window to be in a separate icon in the taskbar (see the EXPECTED part on screenshot).
Can I do this programmatically?

I tried this for Windows (Windows 10).
Not tried for MAC.
I want it to work on both Windows and Mac.

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800,height: 600})
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
  var otherWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 400,height: 300})
  otherWindow.loadFile('otherWindow.html')

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}
app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

[image: Look image]

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
win.setAppDetails({
  appId: "MySecondWindowID"
});
```

Windows groups window icons in the taskbar if they have same [System.AppUserModel.ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-appusermodel-id), you can use `win.setAppDetails(options)` from [Electron API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetappdetailsoptions-windows) to set different `appId`'s for each window.